# Force www to non-www on a subdomain in WordPress?

Tags: htaccess

Forcing www to non-www is simple at the primary domain level.

What about at the subdomain level?

If I am correct the "issue" is that it is at two levels of depth so you can't force a subdomain to be non-www

This is what I mean:

```
https://my.domain.com < correct
https://www.my.domain.com < incorrect and trying to force to non-www
```

Comment: Why would there ever be a link to www.my.domain.com that you’d need to redirect?

Comment: Good point....I guess I was just curious and wanted to 'fix' it

Comment: Regardless, this is probably something you'd address as the hosting level, so it might be something you want to ask you host about. In testing my cPanel hosted subdomains redirected from www, even though I hadn't set up anything specific for that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That certainly isn't default "cPanel" behaviour. It's possible your host might be doing this "automagically" (although that would seem unlikely IMO). It's also possible that any www to non-www redirect you have in place for the main domain is catching the subdomains also?

Answer (score 1):

> Forcing www to non-www is simple at the primary domain level.

It's actually the same for the subdomain (depending on how you've written the directives in the first place). If the hostname (main domain or subdmomain) starts with `www.` then remove it.

(Forcing non-www to www for subdomains *and* main domains is a little more tricky if you want a generic single directive solution.)

The following removes the `www` subdomain from *any* hostname.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In addition... If your subdomains are pointing to subdirectories off the main domain (eg. `example.com/subdomain`) then these subdirectories are probably also accessible and would need to be redirected. (Although search engines shouldn't discover these subdirectories, or the www subdomain for that matter, unless it was *leaked* in some way.)

Comment: @henry How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

This would probably only happen if you are erroneously redirecting to www.my.domain.com in your htaccess. So if that's the case you'll want to review your htaccess to remove the www.my.domain.com redirect.

If that's not the case, ie. you're trying to redirect links that have the wrong subdomain, you'll need to have a catch all subdomain, AKA wildcard subdomain. If you don't have a wildcard subdomain you might as well be redirecting to *thisdoesntexist.my.domain.com*

If you want to redirect links that go to the wrong domain AND you have a wildcard subdomain, put this in your .htaccess file:

```
#FORCE WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://my.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Should work for http and https.

Comment: The first condition that checks the _Host_ is not empty is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove www from any URLs that have them:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What does this add that isn't already covered by the existing answers? This would also seem to be a hardcoded solution for the domain apex only, not any subdomain as stated in the question. Code only answers are generally considered low quality as there is no explanation as to what this actually does.